# How to set Validators pattern is not accepting zero and empty space in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to set the **Validators pattern is not accepting zero and empty space.**

It should not accept inputs `0` and `empty space`. It should accept `1, 50, 4000, 856457858520..` possibly do a limit on it.

Comment: Are you speaking about ng-pattern directive? Could you please provide some code and a bit more explanation?

Comment: For example: date setting
Type script:
manufacturedDate :  ['', Validators.pattern(/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\-(0?[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\-(19|20)\d{2}$/)],
Angular
div *ngIf="manufacturedDate.invalid && (manufacturedDate.dirty || manufacturedDate.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <div *ngIf="manufacturedDate.errors.pattern">
                            Not a valid date.
                     </div>
                </div>

Comment: I am not a big fan of the regexp (as allmost nobody I think) but you can try this one /[1-9]\d*/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and the limited information I would try this;

```
ng-pattern="^[1-9]\d*$"
```